# How to access sibling frame data in HTML?

Tags: html, frames

I have the following HTML files
INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a frameset with OBJECT in the HEAD</title>
  </head>
  <frameset cols="50%,50%">
    <frame src="bianca.html" name="bianca"></frame>
    <frame src="second.html" name="second"></frame>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

BIANCA.HTML

```
<!-- In bianca.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bianca's page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...the beginning of the document...
    <p id="test">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log(window.parent.bianca.document.getElementById("test"));
        console.log(window.parent.second.document.getElementById("test1"));
      </script>
      ...the rest of the document...
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

SECOND.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="test1">From second frame</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output(as logged in the console)is :

```
<p id="test">...</p>
undefined
```

Why is the second line undefined, however if i change the order of the frames in index.html as:

```
<FRAME src="second.html" id="second" name="second"></FRAME>
<FRAME src="bianca.html" id="bianca" name="bianca">
```

then correct output(as expected) is logged. Why is it not working in the first case?

Comment: because the javascript written like that will be evaluated in the order of appearence while parsing the htmls. So `getElementById` won't find the element in the dom parsed so far. You could wrap that code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener for example or use `<script defer>`

Comment: You need to be aware that `<frame>` and `<frameset>` have been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for at least 15 years.